# What protocol is used when user is interacting with node-red dashboard

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt, iot, node-red

I am using MQTT and node red in a wireless plug project.

**Question:**

what is the protocol used when the user interface with the GUI (dashboard)?? when the user clicks on a switch or view the data published by mqtt on the webApp how this is internally handled ? through Web-sockets or what??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about the [node-red-dashboard](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-dashboard) nodes.

Then the page is loaded via HTTP and the updates (both to and from) are sent via WebSockets using the socket.io library.

If you mean the Node-RED Editor (where flows are created/edited) then again the page is loaded over HTTP and the updates (the Node Status and the messages in the debug sidebar) are sent over a WebSocket connection.

Flow Deploys are sent as a HTTP POST